# Buttons sending var to a Jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, button, call, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get this code to work but I must be wrong somewhere.
I have a menu with several buttons. Each Button have a proper ID and different var.

If you click on a button, its var are sent to my "ChangePage" function

in my ChangePage function, there are several conditions, and if they match
then it launches animations on my page.

That's the structure.

so I'm testing the thing now :

I have 2 buttons.

```
$(function() {


//This button triggers the slider   
$('#AddSliderButton').click(function() {
        var AddSlider = 1;
        $(this).click(PageChange);
    });

//This button removes the slider
$('#RemSliderButton').click(function() {
        var AddSlider = 0;
        $(this).click(PageChange);
    });


function PageChange() {
var Slider = 0;   //the slider is not opened by default

if (Slider == 1 && AddSlider == 0) { 
    //Remove slider
    $(".donotshow").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#slider").animate( {"height": "0%"}, "slow");
    $("#wrap-slider").css({"display": "inline"});
    var Slider = 0;
} 
else if (Slider == 0 && AddSlider == 1) {
    //Trigger Slider
    $("#wrap-slider").css({"display": "inline"});
    $(".donotshow").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#slider").animate( {"height": "100%"}, "slow");
    var Slider = 1;
}
else {
    //Do Nothing
    var Slider = 0;
}
}
});
```

I am wondering why my buttons do not call the PageChange function ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Check your variable scopes. Their local to their query functions right now.

Comment: Your first `if` condition will **never** be true, because you're setting `Slider` to 0 just before that and it can therefore never equal `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define both `AddSlider` & `Slider` as global variable.

```
$(function() {

var AddSlider;
var Slider = 0;

//This button triggers the slider   
$('#AddSliderButton').click(function() {
        AddSlider = 1;
        PageChange();
    });

//This button removes the slider
$('#RemSliderButton').click(function() {
        AddSlider = 0;
        PageChange();
    });


function PageChange() {

   if (Slider == 1 && AddSlider == 0) { 
    //Remove slider
    $(".donotshow").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#slider").animate( {"height": "0%"}, "slow");
    $("#wrap-slider").css({"display": "inline"});
    Slider = 0;
   } 
   else if (Slider == 0 && AddSlider == 1) {
    //Trigger Slider
    $("#wrap-slider").css({"display": "inline"});
    $(".donotshow").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#slider").animate( {"height": "100%"}, "slow");
    Slider = 1;
   }
   else {
    //Do Nothing
    Slider = 0;
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: I tryed your way. I think it's a button problem, because the code looks good.

Comment: Ok I figured out what happened : an other function was already modifing the Slider, so that the buttons couldn't work it.

I have another problem : when I click several times on the "Launch" and after "Remove", it stays launched.

Comment: you can use firebug to debug your code. :) It is also better if you provide a jsfiddle or html perhaps.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is : removed the Slider = 1 from Else
and it's working like a charm !

Comment: (I'm new here, Do I need to post the code in my own answer ?)

Comment: Hi @Kazzin, perhaps somewhere in your code you override the value of `Slider`. It will never satisfy the first condition if `Slider` is not set to 1. Anyways, glad you solved it already.

Answer (score 0):

try to call your function like this:

```
$('#AddSliderButton').click(function() {
        var AddSlider = 1;
        PageChange();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).click(PageChange);` is adding another click handler, so the second time the button is clicked, the `PageChange` routine should execute.

Try this instead:

```
$('#AddSliderButton').click(function () {
    var AddSlider = 1;
    PageChange();
});

$('#RemSliderButton').click(function () {
    var AddSlider = 0;
    PageChange();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#AddSliderButton').click(function() {
    var AddSlider = 1;
    PageChange(AddSlider);
});

function PageChange(AddSlider) {
var Slider = 0;   //the slider is not opened by default

if (Slider == 1 && AddSlider == 0) { 
//Remove slider
$(".donotshow").fadeOut("slow");
$("#slider").animate( {"height": "0%"}, "slow");
$("#wrap-slider").css({"display": "inline"});
var Slider = 0;
} 
else if (Slider == 0 && AddSlider == 1) {
//Trigger Slider
$("#wrap-slider").css({"display": "inline"});
$(".donotshow").fadeIn("slow");
$("#slider").animate( {"height": "100%"}, "slow");
var Slider = 1;
}
else {
//Do Nothing
var Slider = 0;
}
}
});
```

Comment: I tryed your way but it's not working
I figured out my mistake : 
I was redefining the var Slider each time, instead of updating it

Comment: so you var Slider should be a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping

```
$(this).click(PageChange);
```

for

```
PageChange();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
PageChange()
```

Instead of

```
$(this).click(PageChange);
```